# SPI clock settings for MSP432

Tags: stm32, spi, msp

SPI is set to use SMCLK but I am confused what the value of BRW (baud rate control) should be. Could someone guide me how to determine this value? The MSP432 (master) is sending a character over to STM32 (slave) using SPI. On the oscilloscope you can see the correct value being transmitted but STM32 sees the wrong value. I have tried BRW = 1 (3Mhz), 2 (1.5Mhz) and 30 (100 Khz) because SMCLK is 3Mhz but I dont think this is right.

Answer (score 1):

The system clock frequency is set in system_msp432pXXX.c file and BRW is the the clock divider. Set the BRW to get the frequency you want.

SPI clock = System clock/BRW value